# Form not submiting using form_with

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I am trying to submit form but unfortunately nothing is hapening, there is no error which i can debug.
When press submit nothing happens, I appreciate your help.

View:

```html
  <div class="modal-body">
          <%= form_with model: Message.new  do |f| %>
            <%= f.hidden_field :receiver_id, value: @users.last.id %>
            <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.text_area :content, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Write Message", rows: "2" %>
            </div> 
            <div class="modal-footer justify-content-end">
                <%= f.submit "Send", class: "btn btn-primary"%>
            </div>  
          <% end %>         
        </div>
```

Routes:

```
  get 'conversations', to: 'conversations#list', as: "conversations"
  get 'conversations/:id', to: 'conversations#show', as: "conversation_detail"
  post 'messages', to: 'messages#create'
```

Messages_controller:

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    if current_user.id == message_params[:received_id]
        redirect_to request.referrer, alert: "You can't"
    end
    conversation = Conversation.where("(sender_id = ? AND receiver_id = ?) OR (sender_id = ? AND receiver_id = ?)", current_user.id, message_params[:receiver_id], message_params[:receiver_id], current_user.id).first

    if !conversation.present?
        conversation = Conversation.create(sender_id: current_user.id, receiver_id: message_params[:receiver_id])
    end
    @message = Message.new(user_id: current_user.id, conversation_id: conversation.id, content: message_params[:content], attachment_file: message_params[:attachment_file])

    if @message.save
        conversation.update!(updated_at: @message.created_at)
         respond_to do |format|
          format.html  # index.html.erb
          format.json  { redirect_to: root_path }
        end
    end
  end

private
    def message_params
        params.require(:message).permit(:content, :receiver_id, :attachment_file)
    end
end
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRafZ.png)

Comment: Form is requesting for ``new`` method which is not present, So add ``new`` method along with ``create`` method.

Comment: Form_with is async by default. It expects your controller to responds js or json. If you don't want async, you have to add `local: true`